# How to handle socket callbacks that dispatches to redux sequentially too much and blocks the app? react-redux batch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In our app, there are some data updates coming via sockets.
In the callbacks of the socket a redux action is dispatched.
Here is an example

```
const onReceiveLocationMessages = function(message) {
      let payload = JSON.parse(message.body);
      console.log("received locations", payload);
      dispatch(onLocationChange(payload));
    };
```

Now occasionally a lot of updates come through socket at once, thus the callback is fired sequentially, so many dispatches are fired as well. This results in app lagging like navigating, opening menus, clicking buttons etc. because as I guess a lot of renders are happening.

I guess something similar to `batch` https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch from react-redux would help here. But as the example shows there it combines multiple dispatches at once, and in this case, it's quick sequential dispatches.

So what's the best practice to handle these kinds of situations?

Comment: It sounds like you want some kind of buffer. there are lots of potential solutions here, maybe have a look at this https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-action-buffer if you used something like redux-observable you could use the built in operators that handle this type of buffering very well https://redux-observable.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not needlessly rendering many parts of your application or having a long running reducer that causes the lag? If you're using pure components with reselect you can prevent components from rendering needlessly and get a less laggy app.

Below is an example of a helper function named `createBatchAction` that does batched updates. You pass the action creator (toggleColorBatched) to the helper and a `batchPeriod` parameter and will return a new action creator thunk that will run all the collected actions within the batch period.

There is another action creator named toggleColorNotBatched that is dispatched together with `batchedToggleColorBatche` (new thunk action created with createBatchAction) but you can see that the batched version updates DOM in batches.

```js
const {
  Provider,
  useDispatch,
  useSelector,
  batch,
} = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
// helper to batch action
const createBatchAction = (actionCreator, batchPeriod) => {
  const data = { dispatch: null, actions: [] };
  setInterval(() => {
    batch(() =>
      data.actions.forEach((action) => data.dispatch(action))
    );
    data.actions = [];
  }, batchPeriod);
  return (...args) => (dispatch) => {
    data.dispatch = dispatch;
    data.actions.push(actionCreator(...args));
  };
};

const ROWS = 10;
const COLS = 20;
const BLUE = 'blue';
const RED = 'red';
const initial = Array(ROWS)
  .fill()
  .map(() =>
    Array(COLS)
      .fill()
      .map(() => ({ color: BLUE }))
  );
const initialState = {
  batched: initial,
  notBatched: initial,
};
const nextItem = ((row, col) => () => {
  col += 1;
  if (col >= COLS) {
    col = 0;
    row += 1;
  }
  if (row >= ROWS) {
    row = 0;
  }
  return { row, col };
})(0, -1);
//action types
const TOGGLE_COLOR_BATHCED = 'TOGGLE_COLOR_BATHCED';
const TOGGLE_COLOR_NOT_BATCHED = 'TOGGLE_COLOR_NOT_BATCHED';
//action creators
const toggleColorBatched = ({ row, col }) => ({
  type: TOGGLE_COLOR_BATHCED,
  payload: { row, col },
});
const toggleColorNotBatched = ({ row, col }) => ({
  type: TOGGLE_COLOR_NOT_BATCHED,
  payload: { row, col },
});
//batched version of toggleColor that batches all actions every second
const batchedToggleColorBatche = createBatchAction(
  toggleColorBatched,
  1000
);
const setToggle = (rows, row, col) =>
  rows.map((val, i) =>
    i === row
      ? val.map((val, i) =>
          i === col
            ? {
                ...val,
                color: val.color === BLUE ? RED : BLUE,
              }
            : val
        )
      : val
  );
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === TOGGLE_COLOR_BATHCED) {
    const { row, col } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      batched: setToggle(state.batched, row, col),
    };
  }
  if (type === TOGGLE_COLOR_NOT_BATCHED) {
    const { row, col } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      notBatched: setToggle(state.notBatched, row, col),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectBatched = (state) => state.batched;
const selectNotBatched = (state) => state.notBatched;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      //adding thunk like middleware
      ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) =>
        typeof action === 'function'
          ? action(dispatch, getState)
          : next(action)
    )
  )
);
// Col only re renders if props passed to it change
const Col = React.memo(function Col({ col }) {
  return <td style={{ color: col.color }}>X</td>;
});
// Row only re renders if props passed to it change
const Row = React.memo(function Row({ row }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      {row.map((col, i) => (
        <Col key={i} col={col} />
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const batched = useSelector(selectBatched);
  const notBatched = useSelector(selectNotBatched);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const item = nextItem();
      dispatch(batchedToggleColorBatche(item));
      dispatch(toggleColorNotBatched(item));
    }, 50);
    const item = nextItem();
    dispatch(batchedToggleColorBatche(item));
    dispatch(toggleColorNotBatched(item));
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h1>batched</h1>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h1>not batched</h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                {batched.map((row, i) => (
                  <Row key={i} row={row} />
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                {notBatched.map((row, i) => (
                  <Row key={i} row={row} />
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```